# How to make foreign key from two different table in third table?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, foreign-keys, sqlplus

I have three tables named as :

```
Staff(id,name,address);
Members(id,name,address);
Plans(id,Userid,type);
```

I want to create Userid from Plans foreign key for both Staff and Members table
How can i do it?

Comment: I am using SQL PLUS with oracle 11g

Answer (score 0):

Umm ... not like that.

Staff and members should be stored in the same table, with additional column (and table to be referenced) which says whether someone is "staff" or "member". Then `plans` table doesn't have a *problem* any more.

```
SQL> create table type_sm
  2    (id_sm       number       constraint pk_tsm primary key,
  3     name        varchar2(20) constraint ch_typ check (name in ('staff', 'member'))
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> create table staff_members
  2    (id_sta_mem  number constraint pk_stamem primary key,
  3     id_sm       number constraint fk_sm_typ references type_sm (id_sm),
  4     name        varchar2(20),
  5     address     varchar2(30)
  6    );

Table created.

SQL> create table plans
  2    (id_pla      number constraint pk_pla primary key,
  3     id_sta_mem  number constraint fk_plastamem references staff_members (id_sta_mem)
  4    );

Table created.

SQL>
```